# Don't save the info if there's a null form in c# sqlClient

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, null

I'm making our system for thesis, and i'm trying to save a account of the users. My condition is, if there's a empty form, the account will not be saved and it will display a message box. I tried to put it in a `if` element, that "If aForm.Text.Trim() != null" the info/account will be saved into database. But when i tried to leave a empty form and click save it still be saved in the database.

Here's the code * ALL OF THE COLUMNS IN SQL IS SET TO "NOT NULL"

```
private void aAddUserSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // it will save the data if all of the forms is not == to null
        // or empty spaces
        // and before the info will be saved
        // the confirm password should be == to the password

        if (aAddUserFirstName.Text.Trim() != null && aAddUserLastName.Text.Trim() != null && aAddUserAddress.Text.Trim() != null && aAddUserContact.Text.Trim() != null && aAddUserPass.Text.Trim() != null &&
            aAddUserPassConfirm.Text.Trim() != null && aAddUserForgotAnswer.Text.Trim() != null && aAddUserPassConfirm.Text == aAddUserPass.Text)
        {
            // location and the command for the database
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\makoy2017\Documents\My files\School Files\Veron System\System Files\DO NOT DELETE\veronServer.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            string query = "INSERT INTO usersAccount (firstName, lastName, address, contactNo, position, password, forgotAnswer) values('" + this.aAddUserFirstName.Text + "', '" + this.aAddUserLastName.Text + "', '" + this.aAddUserAddress.Text +
                "', '" + this.aAddUserContact.Text + "', '" + this.aAddUserPosition.SelectedIndex + "', '" + this.aAddUserPass.Text + "', '" + this.aAddUserForgotAnswer.Text + "');";

            // connecting to the database
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader;

            // try and catch for the saving and reading of the data
            // so if there's a error the system will not close
            // and show the message error
            try
            {
                // open the database connectiont to the system
                sqlConnection.Open();

                // execute the sql command for the sql reader
                sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                // read all of the data
                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {

                }

                // show user saved
                // when the data is saved successfully!
                MessageBox.Show("User Saved!");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // this will show the message box
                // what is the error of the data
                // the data will not be saved in the database
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your confirm/password!");
        }
    }
```

Please help. Make the code simple because i'm still a beginner . Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null` and "an empty string" are not the same thing.  There's a handy helper method to assist with the conditional checks though.  So instead of this:

```
if (aAddUserFirstName.Text.Trim() != null)
```

You can do something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aAddUserFirstName.Text))
```

This will ensure that the string is not:

- null
- an empty string (length 0)
- a non-empty string containing only whitespace characters (what you were doing with `.Trim()`)

**IMPORTANT:** There are other problems with your code.  Primarily, you are wide open to **SQL Injection**.  What this means is that your code is blindly executing any SQL code your users feel like sending it.  Do not directly concatenate user-modifiable values with your SQL code.  Instead, [use query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) and treat user input as *values* instead of as *code*.

Additionally, you don't need to use `ExecuteReader` and *read* data when you're not actually *reading* any data.  You're executing an `INSERT` statement, not a `SELECT`.  Use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.

Comment: what if I need to check 5 forms ? I'm trying to do this " if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aAddUserFirstName.Text, aAddUserLastName.Text)) " but it won't let me

Comment: @MoZenLen: You can use the `&&` operator to combine multiple conditions into a single statement.  For example: `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aAddUserFirstName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aAddUserLastName.Text))`  Just like you already do in your code now.

Comment: I works ! Thank you so much ! and also I change and deleted all the codes I don't needed and it helps me a lot. :)